# Prove a sequence does not tend to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence $\dfrac{a^n}{2^nn^2}$ where $a>2$ does not tend to zero. I thought about writing $a=2+{\epsilon}$ then using binomial expansion which is valid for ${\epsilon}<1$ but couldn't any progress.

Comment: The exponential function increased much faster than any polynomials.

Comment: Try writing $a = 2(1+\epsilon)$ instead, it may be more suggestive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\frac{a^n}{2^nn^2} = \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^nn^2 = \frac{b^n}{n^2}$ with $b > 1$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$\displaystyle\frac{a^n}{2^nn^2}=\frac{a^n}{2^n}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{(1+\epsilon)^n}{n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Consider $\frac{b^n}{n^2}$ as suggested by Darth Geek.

$$ \frac{b^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}  / \frac{b^n}{n^2} = \frac{b}{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} > 1$$

for $b>1$ and $n>N$ for sufficiently large $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion works. Let $\frac{a}{2}=1+b$. By the Binomial Theorem, if $n\ge 2$, then $(1+b)^n \gt \frac{b^2}{2!}n(n-1)$.  But $n-1\ge \frac{n}{2}$. So the $n$-th term of our sequence is $\ge \frac{b^2}{4}$.

By going to the term in $b^3$, we can show that in fact the sequence blows up.